# Draw line between China and South America through the Pacific Ocean in Leaflet

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, line, antimeridian

I am relatively new using Leaflet.js. I want to **draw a [polyline](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polyline) in Leaflet.js between China and South America through the Pacific Ocean**. Instead, I can only draw this line through both places through the Indian Ocean, Africa and the Atlantic Ocean (as you can see in my image).

[image]

I understand that this happen because of the CRS, but I can't figure any solution.

In order to add my code, is this:

```
/* Mapa base en Leaflet */
    let map_1 = L.map('leafletContainer_1', {
        center: [18.0613724, 109.4901601],
        worldCopyJump: true,
        zoom: 2,
        maxZoom: 18,
        minZoom: 1,
        zoomControl: false,
        scrollWheelZoom: false
    });

    L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map_1);

    var pointA = new L.LatLng(36.735683, 122.550628);
    var pointB = new L.LatLng(0.067347, -119.536768);
    var pointList = [pointA, pointB];

    var firstpolyline = new L.Polyline(pointList, {
        color: 'red',
        weight: 3,
        opacity: 1,
        smoothFactor: 1
    });
    firstpolyline.addTo(map_1);
```

Here, point A is China and point B is South America (well, not exactly South America but close enough).

But, I desire that my map draw a polyline like this:

[image]

Do you know if it is any function to do this or if there is any other library to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: I added a link to the polyline object documentation. There is no reason to force the user to provide any literal code here.

Comment: Hi again! I've already edit my comment in order to open again this question. I hope the new comment could be enough. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Official range of longitude coordinates is from -180 to 180 degrees, where latitude 180 (equal to -180) is called antimeridian. Problem with vector features is when they cross antimeridian. Even official GeoJSON specs [3.1.9. Antimeridian Cutting](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.1.9) state that in this case geometry has to be split:

> In representing Features that cross the antimeridian,
> interoperability is improved by modifying their geometry.  Any
> geometry that crosses the antimeridian SHOULD be represented by
> cutting it in two such that neither part's representation crosses the
> antimeridian.

But here Leaflet comes to the rescue. It simply allows latitude coordinates to continue from 180 onward and from -180 backward. This effectively means that latitude 200 means the same meridian on globe as -160 (200 - 360), but on Leaflet map it's shown to the right of the 180 meridian.

Here is an example of a line crossing 180 meridian (right) and similar line crossing opposing -180 meridian (left):

[image]

Left line goes from -235 to -84 longitude, the right one goes from 124 to 275 longitude.